# Why is the Button code on the ArcGIS.com sample viewers so complicated?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, html, dojo

I'm trying to modify one of the [ArcGIS.com sample maps](http://apps.arcgis.com/hosted/OnePane/basicviewer/index.html) to add my own buttons, and I'm surprised at how complicated the HTML page is.

Here is the code for the simple "Details" button at the top left of the header:

```
<span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitToggleButton dijitToggleButtonChecked dijitChecked" widgetid="detailButton">
<span dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode">
    <span aria-labelledby="detailButton_label" role="button" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" style="-moz-user-select: none;" id="detailButton" tabindex="0" title="Display Map Details" aria-pressed="true">
        <span dojoattachpoint="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon esriDetailsIcon"></span>
        <span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span>
        <span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" id="detailButton_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText">Details</span>
    </span>
</span>
<input type="button" dojoattachpoint="valueNode" tabindex="-1" class="dijitOffScreen" value="">
```

The image itself is specified in the CSS.

**Is all that code really necessary, and is there an easier way to add a button (with tooltip) to the interface of an ArcGIS Server JavaScript API map?**

I noted that the [Toolbar sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/toolbar/toolbar_navigation.html) doesn't show tooltips, hence my investigation of the ArcGIS.com samples.

Comment: Welcome to Dojo auto-generated madness

Comment: new [blog post](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp_start.htm#jshelp/why_dojo.htm) from Esri explaining why dojo is used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the markup generated by dojo for a specific kind of widget (dijit). You wouldn't actually build that yourself– it's the result of creating a dijit (either declaratively or programmatically).

There are a number of button-style dijits available:

- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/Button.html
- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/ComboButton.html
- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/DropDownButton.html
- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/ToggleButton.html

Comment: ah - so I shouldn't be looking at the HTML page, but instead at the JS code which creates those buttons. That makes sense - thanks

Comment: @StephenLead yep, exactly

Comment: ...and thats why ESRI needs to stop using Dojo.

Comment: @DonnyV. The markup generated by dojo is optional when using Esri's API. It's up to you whether you use a native html <button>, <input type="button"> or a dijit. The advantage of using dijits is you get buttons that look the same cross-browser. To get a consistent look cross-browser requires additional markup, and that's what dojo generates. You rarely have to worry about working with that markup directly (there are some cases where you might want to tweak some CSS). This is helpful for some background:  http://davidwalsh.name/dojo-widget Full-disclosure:  I work for Esri on the JS API team.

Comment: @DonnyV.very constructive comment. Really added no value. Dojo adds the extra markup to 1 add aria support, which iirc no other js ui language does, and 2 to style the buttons to look the same across browsers like derek said. These extra dom elements are no reason why esri should stop using dojo.

Comment: You don't need all that markup to be cross browser. Last time I checked the anchor tag worked in every browser.                         `<a href="#" class="myButton">my button</a>`  You can use css to style it however you want [cssbuttongenerator.com](http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com)

Comment: @DonnyV. if that works for you/your app, there's nothing stopping you from going that route.

Answer (score 2):

`<button onClick=_onButtonClick>?</button>`

Most of that code is to make the button 'pretty'. You'll need to use the Dojo dijits stuff to put the map on the page, but you could fall back to plain old HTML a lot of the time.

Comment: Thanks - and any best-practices for the tooltips? [dijit.tooltip](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Tooltip.html)?